# How to access and parse the source frame in a python web scraping application on a classic asp website

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, frame

I'm trying to create a web-crawler application that downloads a bunch of assorted PDFs from SAI using this tutorial as my basis
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVNJOiTBi_8

I've tried get(url) on the website I believe I want to get the source from

Authentication code (not included) ....

```
def subscription_spider(max_pages):
page = 1
while page <= max_pages:
    url= 'https://www.saiglobal.com/online/Script/listvwstds.asp?TR=' + str(page)
    source_code = session.get(url) # need to get the frame source!!
    # extra code to find the href for the frame than get the frame source
#https://www.saiglobal.com/online/Script/ListVwStds.asp

    plain_text = source_code.text #source_code.text printed is not the one we want

    playFile = open('source_code.text', 'wb')
    for chunk in r.iter_content(100000):
            playFile.write(chunk)
    playFile.close()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code.content, features='html.parser') 
    for link in soup.findAll('a',{'class':'stdLink'}): #can't find the std link
        href= "https://www.saiglobal.com/online/" + link.get('href')
        '''
        get_pdf(href)
        ''' 
        print(href)
    page += 1

'''
#function will probably give a bad name to the files but can fix this later
def get_pdf(std_url)
    source_code = session.get(std_url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    for link in soup.select("a[href$='.pdf']"):
        #Name the pdf files using the last portion of each link which are unique in this case
        filename = os.path.join(folder_location,link['href'].split('/')[-1])
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(session.get(urljoin(url,link['href'])).content)
'''
r = session.get("https://www.saiglobal.com/online/")
print (r.status_code)

subscription_spider(1)

r = session.get("https://www.saiglobal.com/online/Script/Logout.asp") #not sure if this logs out or not
print (r.status_code)
```

The text file creates this

```
<frameset rows="*, 1">
<frame SRC="Script/Login.asp?">
<frame src="Script/Check.asp" noresize>
</frameset>
```

but when I inspect the element what I want is in a frame source which i cant directly access, i think the issue has something to do with the structure of classic asp pages but im not really sure what to do
[html element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKG7i.png)

The output of the program is

200
200 
press any key to continue...

Comment: The fact the source URL is Classic ASP has no bearing on the question because the web crawler will only see the client generated HTML so the process will be the same regardless of the server-side coding used.

Comment: It's moreso I am confused as to whether the some of the .asp files have  to be rendered or not with respect to the html element link I provided, that's why I mentioned it. Maybe I didn't provide enough information?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean, a URL is a URL. HTML is rendered the same regardless of how it was generated *(static, server-side script, compiled etc)*.

Comment: I want this https://imgur.com/qqY0R0F (seen when clicking view frame source: https://imgur.com/AYQEqLL) but i get this  https://imgur.com/LF8YDRY (seen when clicking view source of website) as the output of my textfile (to check what my program is parsing). The website looks like this https://imgur.com/KdU5Cor . What I believe is happening is my request isn't getting the full html page but only part of it as some elements are loaded after some kind of script, not sure if .asp works as a script but the frame exists with a .asp src. Thanks :)

Comment: Do you understand what a frameset is? Just as you have to click Frame Source to see the underlying HTML the same is true here, the frameset contains two pages just go directly to their URLs *(i.e. `https://www.saiglobal.com/online/Script/Login.asp?`)* and you'll see the relevant HTML.